# Encrypted SQL Server connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have a connection string which has been encode by some algorithm.

I need help to find out the algorithm for this connect .
Thanks

I have tried the Base64 but it's not correct

```
<add connectionString ="w3jjXeiXMl5qd5DtbUCSrwPGs0Nd+1ZIPqnOaprSlicxvltKoVYu+3wN4+DrJFo678tzvj7eHRy87qMPAH5GTp1MH58Xx2SlPFXZrHaLmH6FGmvZeY66wa/tSaL5zOgT" />
```

Comment: I think you need the key...This is the point of encryption...you cant unencrypt it unless you have the key.

Comment: Well, i just need to find out which algorithm use to encode this string. Because it's 1024 byte so i guest it use RSA, right ?

Comment: Use this method... Its so clear and simple: please tell use about result. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config

Answer (score 0):

why use encryption? I suggest. Use SSPI...

Use this help :

[Connection String Syntax](http://Connection%20String%20Syntax)
In this model you dont need password... in connection string.
you can remove windows authentication and change Sa password. its so safe.

Trusted Connection

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Trusted Connection

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServerAddress;
```

Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;

```
Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
```

Trusted_Connection=yes;

Prompt for username and password
This one is a bit tricky. First you need to set the connection object's Prompt property to adPromptAlways. Then use the connection string to connect to the database.

```
oConn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways

oConn.Open "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;"
```

Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver
Trusted connection

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
```

Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Use an ODBC driver from .NET

```
Driver={any odbc driver's name};OdbcKey1=someValue;OdbcKey2=someValue;
```

Comment: You can't always use SSPI - think Azure SQL Server ..... there's no concept of "Windows authentication" in Azure .....

Comment: I used **SSPI**  in windows, web form and apk... but i don't use azure

Comment: Many thanks, but i need to find out the algorithm which has been used to find a way to decode it only

Comment: Check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config

Answer (score 0):

It's using a symmetric block cipher, most likely AES or TripleDES.
The encrypted data is using Zero padding.

You are not going to be able to decrypt this connection string unless you have the Key and the IV.